# Как поймать событие .change при программном изменении значения элемента <input>

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

В форме есть элемент `<input>`, а рядом с ним бутстрапный `dropdown button`, который по клику пишет значения в этот `input`. Нужно на `input` навесить событие `change`, которое будет срабатывать при изменении значения как вручную (с клавиатуры), так и программно - скриптом. У меня событие ловится только при изменении с клавиатуры.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button ...>Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#action1">Action1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#action2">Action2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input type="text">
</div>

<script>
    $('form .dropdown-menu a').on('click', function() {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find('input')[0];
        input.value = this.hash.substr(1);
    });
    $('input').on('change', function() { alert(); })
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    $('form .dropdown-menu a').on('click', function() {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find('input')[0];
        input.value = this.hash.substr(1);

        // решил вот таким образом
        $('input').trigger('change');

    });
    $('input').on('change', function() { alert(); })
</script>
```